# SSAS 2012 role fails to start in a Win 2012 cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clustering, ssas

I started a thread in [MSDN SSAS Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b837a906-7d44-43f6-8e3d-ed9597368003/ssas-2012-service-not-starting-up?forum=sqlanalysisservices#5a044273-0264-455a-8249-0fb6884162a6).  Please see this and help me understand the problem. I have never seen this sort of issue before. I'll try to explain the issue here as well.

I got SQL Server installed in a failover cluster environment.  SQL Server, Agent Service & Analysis Service. Everything was working well. Without any apparent reason SSAS service stopped working one day. There was no installation of any sort before this event. Whenever I try to start SSAS, I get the following error:
[image]

I checked the SSAS log file and I see below entries.

```
(3/26/2017 3:46:14 PM) Message: The Query thread pool now has 1 minimum threads, 10 maximum threads, and a concurrency of 8.  Its thread pool affinity mask is 0x000000000000000f. (Source: \\?\L:\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, Type: 1, Category: 289, Event ID: 0x4121000A)
(3/26/2017 3:46:14 PM) Message: The ParsingShort thread pool now has 4 minimum threads, 4 maximum threads, and a concurrency of 8.  Its thread pool affinity mask is 0x000000000000000f. (Source: \\?\L:\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, Type: 1, Category: 289, Event ID: 0x4121000A)
(3/26/2017 3:46:14 PM) Message: The ParsingLong thread pool now has 4 minimum threads, 4 maximum threads, and a concurrency of 8.  Its thread pool affinity mask is 0x000000000000000f. (Source: \\?\L:\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, Type: 1, Category: 289, Event ID: 0x4121000A)
(3/26/2017 3:46:14 PM) Message: The Processing thread pool now has 1 minimum threads, 64 maximum threads, and a concurrency of 8.  Its thread pool affinity mask is 0x000000000000000f. (Source: \\?\L:\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, Type: 1, Category: 289, Event ID: 0x4121000A)
(3/26/2017 3:46:14 PM) Message: The IOProcessing thread subpool with affinity 0x000000000000000f now has 1 minimum threads, 64 maximum threads, and a concurrency of 8. (Source: \\?\L:\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, Type: 1, Category: 289, Event ID: 0x4121000B)
(3/26/2017 3:46:14 PM) Message: Failed to initialize SQLSQM timer. One of the following can be the source of the problem: registry doesn't contain all necessary information, server instance name can not be retrieved correctly, failure during timer creation, etc. (Source: \\?\L:\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, Type: 3, Category: 289, Event ID: 0xC121001B)
(3/26/2017 3:46:15 PM) Message: The service cannot be started:  (Source: \\?\L:\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, Type: 3, Category: 289, Event ID: 0xC1210000)
(3/26/2017 3:46:15 PM) Message: Service stopped. (Source: \\?\L:\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, Type: 1, Category: 2
```

Below is Failover Cluster Manager event log details

```
1. Cluster resource 'Analysis Services' of type 'Generic Service' in clustered role 'SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)' failed.

   Based on the failure policies for the resource and role, the cluster service may try to bring 
   the resource online on this node or move the group to another node of the cluster and then 
   restart it.  Check the resource and group state using Failover Cluster Manager or the 
   Get-ClusterResource Windows PowerShell cmdlet.

2. Generic service 'Analysis Services' failed with error '0'. Please examine the application event log.
```

**Other info, which may help you understand the issue further**

1. I'm restricted to add further links here. So, please check the link above

How can I get SSAS to start?

Comment: Instead of directing people offsite (even to MSDN forums), please encapsulate the problem here with enough details for our viewers, and future visitors with a similar issue, to understand.  Thanks!  Also, please take the [tour] and read the [help].

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done so far? e.g. looking at the event log, may be?

Comment: I tried encapsulating whole issue and what is done so far here itself. It seems I don't have enough reputation here to post more than 2 image links. So, please see the link I have given.

Comment: @AbdulGafoorGK - once you get more reputation, you'll be able to post images.  Until then, you can still post links to the images, and one of us will edit them into your question for you.

Comment: However, instead of posting images, we prefer text error messages since it is easier to understand, and can be indexed by search engines, etc.

Comment: Thanks Max. It seems I'm a bit out of line in the way I asked question. I will edit the question to have max info here itself.